# json array post ado.net net core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

estoy construyendo una web api con net core, requiero utilizar el método post para guardar la información de un archivo json, el inconveniente es que el archivo json tiene un array y no se como hacer para enviarle la información al procedimiento almacenado en sql para que este guarde la información  el archivo json es este

```
"buyer": { // 
   "firstName": "fabio",
   "lastName": "gomez",
   "documentType": 0, // Puede ser 0: DNI, 1: Pasaporte o 2: Carnet de Extranjeria
   "documentNumber": "01234567", // Permitir letras para pasaportes extranjeros
   "phoneNumber": "51912345678",
   "email": "hnos@gmail.com"
 },
 "passengers": [{ // En el primer pasajero, pueden repetirse los datos del comprador
     "seat": 1,
     "firstName": "pedro",
     "lastName": "peres", // Considerar nueva campo 
     "secondLastName": "martinez",
     "documentType": 0, // Puede ser 0: DNI, 1: Pasaporte o 2: Carnet de Extranjeria
     "documentNumber": "15588",
     "age": 42,
     "gender": 0, // Puede ser 0: Masculino, 1: Femenino
   },
   {
     "seat": 2,
     "firstName": "Adriana",
     "lastName": "gomez",
     "secondLastName": "lopez",
     "documentType": 1, // Puede ser 0: DNI, 1: Pasaporte o 2: Carnet de Extranjeria
     "documentNumber": "XY01234567",
     "age": 40,
     "gender": 1, // Puede ser 0: Masculino, 1: Femenino
   }
 ],
```

Esta json debe entrar al sistema via post, el cual utilizo el siguiente controlador

```
[HttpPost]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] List<string> valores)
        {
             await _repository.Insert(valores);
            return Ok();


        }
```

intente realizar algo con ado.net pero no me sale bien

```
   public async Task Insert(List<string> parametros)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_insertarpasajero", sql))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", parametros));

                    await sql.OpenAsync();
                    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

No se como pasar la información del controlador que recibe el post a un objeto o datatable para luego utilizar en un procedimiento almacenado
Agradezco su colaboración

Answer (score 1):

Tienes dos opciones: puedes desde .NET recorrer la información del array de pasajeros, y llamar a BBDD uno a uno. Es lo más sencillo pero si buscas buena performance, la solución un poco más trabajada es la siguiente:

Si quieres enviar de una vez el array de pasajeros a sql, vas bien encaminado con ado.net, pero necesitas pasar como parámetro un dataTable. Tendrás que construir este DataTable a partir de tu JSON con las estructura de los viajeros (seat, firstname, lastname...).

Por otro lado en BBDD para que un procedimiento almacenado admita como parámetro de entrada ese DataTable debes crear un "tipo definido por el usuario de tipo tabla". Es como definir una tabla, que tendría las columnas de la tabla "pasajeros".

En este post tengo un ejemplo completamente implementado , con código y paso a paso que creo que te puede ayudar
https://enigmasoftwarelabs.blogspot.com/2020/04/test-3-son-eficientes-los-orms.html

Más bien hacia el final del post hay un subtítulo que dice "Grabando miles de registros con ADO.NET + Reflection + Datatable + Procedimiento Almacenado"

A partir de ahí queda todo bien explicado. Merece la pena aprender esta técnica ya que es una forma muy eficiente de hacer volcados de datos

Saludos

**EDIT_1: Pasando el array a un dataTable**: le planteo el sistema más sencillo. Tal vez pudiera interesarle pasar primero a un objeto (clase) para hacer las pertinentes validaciones de datos.

```
public DataTable GetDatatableFromJson(string json)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(DataTable)));

    return dt;
}
```

**TEST:**

```
[TestMethod]
public void JsonArrayToDDBB()
{
    string strJSONPassengers = @"[{ 
                                'seat': 1,
                                'firstName': 'pedro',
                                'lastName': 'peres', 
                                'documentType': 0, 
                                },
                                {
                                'seat': 2,
                                'firstName': 'Adriana',
                                'lastName': 'gomez',
                                'documentType': 1, 
                            }]";

    DataTable dt = _csharpfunctions.GetDatatableFromJson(strJSONPassengers);

    Assert.IsTrue(dt.Rows.Count == 2);
    Assert.IsTrue(dt.Rows[1][1].ToString() == "Adriana");
}
```

**EDIT_2: Creando un parámetro de entrada en el SP que admita el DataTable**:
Para poder admitir como parámetro de entrada su DataTable debe crear un tipo definido por el usuario, de tipo tabla (Presupongo un SQL SERVER)

Las columnas del tipo definido SQL SERVER debe coincidir con las columnas del datatable. Siguiendo su ejemplo se crearía así:

```
CREATE TYPE [test].[PassengerType] AS TABLE(
    [seat] [int] NOT NULL,
    [firstName] [nvarchar](155) NOT NULL,
    [lastName] [nvarchar](155 NOT NULL,
    [documentType] tinyint NOT NULL
)
```

Una vez creado puede encontrarlo en su base de datos en programmability -> types -> user defined table types
Su procedimiento almacenado puede así admitir un parámetro de tipo PassengerType, que contendría el array de viajeros. Dentro del procedimiento la variable @Passengers funciona igual que una tabla. De hecho es una variable de tipo tabla:

```
alter procedure [test].[insertViajeros]
@Passengers     test.PassengerType readonly
as
begin
    select * from @Passengers
end
```

Desde la capa de datos puede enlazar el **dataTable** con el parámetro del procedimiento igual que cualquier otro parámetro

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Passengers", DataTablePassengers));
```

Comment: Digo "Tienes dos opciones" pues como una forma de hablar. Seguro que hay más de dos opciones ;)

Comment: Hola vi el el blog suyo, pero no me queda claro como crear el datatable y como enviarle la información json, si me podría aclarar mejor se lo agradezco

Comment: Hola se lo intentaré ir aclarando editando la respuesta, pero no voy a poder hacerlo de una vez. Saludos.

Comment: Hola, agradezco su tiempo y paciencia, modifique el codigo, un poco pero sigo sin poder digamos recibir la informacion via post para luego poder hacer correr el procedimiento almacenado

Comment: Hola, no se si persiste el problema. He vuelto a revisar su consulta y me pregunto si le llegan informaciones a su método Post([FromBody] List<string> valores). Me estaba fijando que tal vez sea más aconsejable que el POST no sea una lista de strings, sino un único string con el contenido íntegro del fichero.